# Как засунуть функцию в переменную python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, переменные

Я хочу сделать функцию которая бы вызывала функцию в плане:

```
def hello:
    print("Hello")

func(hello())

def func(func_v):
    func_v
```

я пробывал через лямбду но у меня не получилось

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def func(f):
    f()

def hello():
    print('Hello')

func(hello)
```

Comment: Ладно, это было легко, странно что я не догадался, но все же спасибо за помощь))

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)